# Automatically registering nodes in rudder

Tags: rudder

In Rudder there is a concept of a node inventory and a manual step, to Accept the node. In static topologies this works quite well, and the manual step to add the machines to the "Accepted" inventory is not a problem.

In environments where servers can be spun up and down rapildly though (for example : In auto-scaling environments) this causes an issue. As the server farm is changing very dynamically.

So, is there a way for new nodes, to be automatically added to the inventory, bypassing the need to "Accept New Nodes".

Comment: @sunny J, Google cloud is just an example of auto scaling , it is not relevant to the question in my view

Comment: Hi, could you please provide more details. Are you referring to a response to the above question "Automatically registering nodes in rudder"? or another question on auto-scaling?

Comment: As far as there's a feature/option in Rudder Node Management tool that supports this. As per Rudder [documentation](https://www.rudder-project.org/doc-4.3/accept-new-nodes.html) it seems to be done manually. This [proposal](https://www.rudder-project.org/redmine/issues/4248) is over a old, and is about Auto Accept list.